# Issue with mybatis-spring integration

Tags: mybatis

I am trying to integrate spring with mybatis.I have done all the configuartions.
I have following versions :
Spring : 3.0.6
Mybatis : 3.0.6
mybatis-spring : 1.0.2

When I use above combination of jars ,at the startup of tomcat,it throws exception that SqlSessionFactoryBean classNotFound and when I actually check mybatis-spring-1.0.2 jar ,SqlSessionFactoryBean is actually not there.

Then I switched to mybatis-spring-1.2.0
Now on using this jar ,on server startup ,I get following error message :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ibatis/mapping/VendorDatabaseIdProvider
```

Configurations used are :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    <!-- org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource" -->
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.10.10.10:1521:xe"/>
        <property name="username" value="uname"/>
        <property name="password" value="pwd"/>
    </bean>

<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/mybatis-config.xml"/> 
    </bean>

<bean id="transactionDao" class="com.abc.daoImpl.TransactionDaoImpl">
        <property name="sqlSessionFactory" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
    </bean>
```

Can you please let me know,what is probelm here .
Thanks in advance.

Comment: basically i am struggling with getting right combination of jars for spring+ibatis configuration.Can anybody who has already worked on spring +mybatis integration can let me know which versions are comatible with each other.Latest I tried mybatis-3.0.4 and mybatis-spring-1.0.0 and spring-3.0.5,but i am getting following exceptionorg.apache.ibatis.builder.xml.XMLConfigBuilder.<init>(Ljava/io/InputStream;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Properties;)V
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)

Comment: I changed to following jars :Spring: 3.0.6, mybatis-3.0.6,mybatis-spring-1.0.0 and above exceptions are gone ,but now i am getting following exception :Error creating bean with name 'sqlSessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: connection timeout normally means there is a database connection error?

Comment: I am using the spring-mybatis combination. Following are the versions which I am using right now which work absolutely fine for me. This may help you.
Spring: 3.2.4.RELEASE
MyBatis: 3.2.4
mybatis-spring: 1.2.2

Answer (score 0):

This class belongs to Ibatis and not MyBatis. Make sure that you have Ibatis as either direct dependency or transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

I set it this way:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>


<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
  <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="mx.com.dctechnology.model"/>
  <property name="mapperLocations" value="classpath*:mx/com/dctechnology/dao/maps/*.xml" />
</bean>


<bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">
  <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
  <property name="basePackage" value="mx.com.dctechnology.dao" />
</bean>
```

Used in pom.xml:

```
<mybatis.version>3.4.1</mybatis.version>
<mybatis-spring.version>1.3.0</mybatis-spring.version>


<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis</artifactId>
    <version>${mybatis.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
    <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
    <version>${mybatis-spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```